# Python installed radian running issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed the radian through python prompt (Anaconda3):

```
(base) C:\Users\rtv233>pip3 install -U radian
Processing c:\users\rtv233\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\f3\22\9f\951f139d5cfd01b958915243e6f137cdae725ef7a332a52033\radian-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.36 in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from radian) (0.3.36)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: prompt-toolkit<3.1,>=3.0 in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from radian) (3.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pygments>=2.5.0 in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from radian) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.9.0 in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.36->radian) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cffi>=1.10.0 in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.36->radian) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wcwidth in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1,>=3.0->radian) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycparser in d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.10.0->rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.36->radian) (2.20)
Installing collected packages: radian
Successfully installed radian-0.6.0
```

After I installed it, I tried to run the radian in python prompt and it turns out to be some error:

```
(base) C:\Users\rtv233>radian
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\Scripts\radian.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\app.py", line 108, in main
    RadianApplication(r_home, ver=__version__).run(options, cleanup=cleanup)
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\app.py", line 215, in run
    self.session = create_radian_prompt_session(options, settings)
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\prompt_session.py", line 152, in create_radian_prompt_session
    session = RadianPromptSession(
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\lineedit\prompt.py", line 72, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts\prompt.py", line 463, in __init__
    self.default_buffer = self._create_default_buffer()
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\lineedit\prompt.py", line 163, in _create_default_buffer
    return ModalBuffer(
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\lineedit\buffer.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\radian\lineedit\buffer.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\buffer.py", line 316, in __init__
    self.history.load(new_history_item)
TypeError: load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with *the language* `R`?

Comment: Because I plan to use radian to show the better terminal R in vscode. It is based on Python but it is used for R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, the creator randy3k [mentioned](https://github.com/randy3k/radian/issues/345) it was due to an old version of prompt-toolkit, so you can update it using your preferred method i.e. `pip3 install prompt-toolkit --upgrade`